# Diagnosing jumpy/buggy-Angular Animations, (i.e. whats is the source of the bug, CSS/code/ng-directives?) BONUS: XKCD

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, uiviewanimation, angularjs-digest

just made an XKCD app for a mean stack class Im taking, and Im getting pretty close to being done, but one doggone visual bug thats pestering me, with angular animations:
here is my deployed app:

https://desolate-savannah-69543.herokuapp.com/#/
and here is the code:
https://github.com/nevaldiv/project4_relevant_xkcd

the issue is likely in my CSS I think the animations.css specifically, but am unsure.

but CSS is not my specialty so, really dont know.
for example, if you click on the checkbox filter for 2008 over and over, you can see that the ng-repeat div's popup slightly to the right? and 'ghost' or leave trails as they pop into their final resting position more towards the left, the heck is causing that? is that some CSS stuff outside of my angular-animations.css causing that? how can I diagnose that if its so fast and then gone, I feel like I need experienced eyes on it.
Ive tried but for the life of me cant seem to figure out what the heck is causing it.
anyway, feel free to tinker on my app thingy, I didnt have enough time to tie together my token auth with (or my user model with my comics model at all, even, besides schematically) anything, so its mostly just what you see on the landing page thats all the meat I got.

Comment: Hi there! The down-voters will come soon enough, but ideally you should reduce the problem down to a small test case, and provide the code here rather than linking to your whole website and asking what's wrong. Anyway, the .animate-repeat class has a CSS transition which causes that. To debug, you can increase the time on that and it should let you see what's going on better.

Answer (score 0):

some more info (cant post more than 2 links) 
here is the link to potential trouble code:
https://github.com/nevaldiv/project4_relevant_xkcd/blob/master/public/css/animations.css#L72